# How can I make a container layout like this?

Tags: html, css, containers, space

I tried to make a container that repeat the panel of posts again and again such blogs but I can't make the spaces disappear.

So the picture will show what I need.

Pic 1:
[image]

Pic 2:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNpGp.png]

As images show, I need to remove spaces from pic 1 and can't do it.

Please give me an HTML with CSS file to make like the second image.

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) in which you reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some jQuery plugins for this.
 For example [mansonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) or [isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/).
I think an css only solution will not work.

Maybe with display: table, display:table-cell this also works with css.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
ul {float: left; width: 430px; padding: 0 14px 0 0; list-style: none}
ul li{color: #fff; background:#333; min-height: 155px; margin: 0 0 7px 0}

.first{height: 318px}
.last{height: 590px}
</style>

<body>

<ul>
    <li class="first">Your content here</li>
    <li>Your content here</li>
    <li>Your content here</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>Your content here</li>
    <li>Your content here</li>
    <li>Your content here</li>
    <li>Your content here</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="last">Your content here</li>
</ul>

</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tS3Wr/

This will help you